# Overriding the User Admin Form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm trying to override the `SonataUser/Admin/Model/UserAdmin`'s `configureFormFields()` because I need to remove some default fields from the admin form.
So I have copied the file `vendor/bundles/Sonata/UserBundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php` in my bundle `app/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php` and modified it. Then declared it as a service:

```
# app/application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    application_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
        arguments: [%sonata_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: application_user_admin }
```

Now questions:
Am I doing right ? How can I tell sonata admin to use it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The overriding class should be set in config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sonata_user:
  admin:
    user:
      class:      MyCompany\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
```

Extend original UserAdmin:

```
namespace MyCompany\UserBundle\Admin\Model;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class UserAdmin extends \Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
{

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        // new logic
    }

}
```

Of course change class name `MyCompany\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin` to reflect your bundle structure.

Answer (score 2):

It is a better practice to keep your bundles in the src directory instead: (See Creating a bundle [section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html)).
In this case, if you are using easy extends, make sure to use `--dest=src` in order to generate the bundle inside an Application namespace in src/.

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle --dest=src
```

By creating your overriding bundle in `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle` and registering the vendor bundle as a parent, you won't have to create a new service. This explains you how to override the bundle properly: [overriding a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) and should save you a lot of time.

Don't forget to create the file you want to override in the same location as your parent bundle.
In your case, you would have to copy paste `SonataUser/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php` from the vendor into your bundle `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php` and modify it as you wish.
That's why overriding bundles can be so useful.

Comment: Actually I used [SonataEasyExtends](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html) to extend the SonataUser Bundle (as told in the [docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-0/doc/reference/introduction.html)), it automatically creates the structure of the extending bundle. It's using `/app/Application` by default, I left it because it's always mentioned like that in SonataUser docs.

Comment: If you specify no parameter, the files are generated in app/Application/Sonata... but you can specify the path with --dest=src. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I saw that (I intentionally left it because they are still using this path in the docs. I'll move it later maybe). The question is more about the way to tell sonata to use my new Admin class.

Comment: You can still override the class instead of creating a new service anyway. Good luck :-)

Comment: That's what I did (see my question), but this class don't get overridden.

Comment: I see. That's surprising. Just to confirm, does your bundle override the vendor bundle properly by using the function getParent()?

Comment: Yes this is done automatically by EasyExtends. Entities and translations from this bundle are already taken into account (extended). There seems to be [something](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonata-users/Hp3P781GKI0/discussion) to declare in the config