# How to override SonataUser entities properties and forms?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I am setting up a brand new project using Symfony 2.7.x and Sonata Admin 2.3.x plus Sonata User. By default Sonata add a bunch of useless fields and I want to keep my entity as clean as possible. So my first question is:

- It's possible to override Sonata User entities in order to get ride of some useless properties? How?

Now as second part of the question and related to the same I want to create or use my own form for add new Users and/or Groups because with defaults ones I can't add roles. See the image below to see what I am talking about:

[image: Sonata Group Add]

I should be able to add new dynamic roles from there and I can't.

- Is this possible? How? Any workaround?

I took a look at Github [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle) and Docs [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/index.html) but couldn't find nothing helpful. Any advices?

Comment: Do not use SonataUserBundle use FOSUserBundle only instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove fields from the admin user create page of Sonata User Bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690298/how-to-remove-fields-from-the-admin-user-create-page-of-sonata-user-bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the Sonata properties by extending the `FOSUserBundle` entity directly rather than SonataUser User model.

change the entity that your User extends actually:

```
use Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
```

to the following:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

Then, to delete useless properties from forms and maybe add new, override the default sonata UserAdmin class:

1- Create an admin class called UserAdmin in your own bundle.

2- Open the file vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Admin/Model/UserAdmin.php and take the `configureFormFields` from it. Paste it in your own admin class and keep only the fields you need by deleting useless fields from the base form builder.

The class can looks like:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class UserAdmin extends Admin // You can extends directly from SonataUserAdmin if it's easier for you
{
    protected $userManager;

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
           ... The fields you keep ...
    }

    /**
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     */
    public function setUserManager(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return UserManagerInterface
     */
    public function getUserManager()
    {
        return $this->userManager;
    }
}
```

3- Define the new UserAdmin class as a service

```
services:
    sonata.user.admin.user:
        class: YourOwnAdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: %sonata.user.admin.groupname%, label: "User", label_catalogue: %sonata.user.admin.label_catalogue%", icon: "%sonata.user.admin.groupicon%"}
        arguments:
            - ~
            - %sonata.user.admin.user.entity%
            - %sonata.user.admin.user.controller%
        calls:
            - [setUserManager, ["@fos_user.user_manager"]]
            - [setTranslationDomain, ["%sonata.user.admin.user.translation_domain%"]]
```

Then, adapt the configuration of sonata-user in config.yml:

```
sonata_user: 
    ...
    admin:
        user:
            class:          YourOwnAdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle
```

And it should be good.

Look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413240/overriding-the-user-admin-form) in case of I forgotten something or you need more.